# How to cut a horizontal line by a perpendicular line?

Tags: xy-pic

I'd like to cut the line *AC* at the point *p* by a perpendicular line.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xypic}
\begin{document}
\xymatrix{
& B\ar @{-}[d] &\\
A\ar @{-}[rr]_{P} &  & C
  }
\end{document}
```

Comment: @MdKutubuddinSardar: Why don't you react to any of the comments?

Comment: Please, at least have the decency to upvote and accept answers to your questions.

Answer (score 10):

To extend the vertical line down to the line AC, use the arrow adjustment facility placing `+0{}` after the arrow.  By default the arrow stops short of the center of the node, this adjustment makes it stop distance `0` from the center instead.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xypic}

\begin{document}
Adjusted:
\xymatrix{
& B\ar @{-}[d]+0{} &\\
A\ar @{-}[rr]_{P} &  & C
  }

Unadjusted:
\xymatrix{
& B\ar @{-}[d] &\\
A\ar @{-}[rr]_{P} &  & C
  }

\end{document}
```

Such adjustments are described in Section 2.6 of the [xypic User guide](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xypic) with something like this set as an exercise.